# Функции-члены в numpy records?

Tags: python, numpy

Мне надо использовать питонские нампайские записи для скорости доступа и экономии памяти. 
Но не хватает возможности задавать функции-члены (методы) к этим записям. Например, хочу делать вот так:

```
X=ones(3, dtype=dtype([('foo', int), ('bar', float)]))
X[1].incrementFooBar()
```

Если были бы просто объекты, сделал бы так:

```
class QQQ:
  ...
  def incrementFooBar(self):
    self.foo+=1
    self.bar+=1
pass
X=[QQQ(),QQQ(),QQQ()]
X[1].incrementFooBar()
```

Как сделать то же самое, но с нампайскими записями?

Comment: Я голосую за закрытие этого вопроса как не соответствующего теме, потому что вопрос должен быть задан на русском языке.

Comment: MaxU, "this" не релевантен.

Comment: насколько важно для вас иметь возможность вызывать функцию так `X[1].incrementFooBar()`, вместо `incrementFooBar(X[1])`?